# How to rectify this issues: asp.net PageRequestManagerParserErrorException

Tags: asp.net

i have a search panel where on click of search button im getting this exception this is for the first time, subsequent click it result the proper result.

Can any one explain how solve the issue.

error message:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   The Message received from the server
>   could not be  parsed.Coommon causes
>   for this error are when the response
>   is modified by Calls to
>   Repose.Write(), response
>   filters,HttpModules, or server trace
>   is enabled. Details:Error Parsing near
>   ' |  '.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using update panel and using response.write both at the same time, (or using register script ) please post your code (sample minified) so that we can give more proper hint